How to force SummingMergeTree do the summing
Found a strange(?) behaviour: when importing several hundred GB of data, aggregation works with a delay even if you force optimization process.
Here is the process:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp.table
(
    date     Date, 
    session  String, 
    total    Int32
)
ENGINE = SummingMergeTree
ORDER BY ( date, session );

-- Importing '2024-01-01'
INSERT INTO temp.table
SELECT date, session, sum(n) AS total FROM temp.data WHERE date = '2024-01-01' GROUP BY date, session
SETTINGS async_insert = 1;

-- Importing '2024-01-02'
INSERT INTO temp.table
SELECT date, session, sum(n) AS total FROM temp.data WHERE date = '2024-01-02' GROUP BY date, session
SETTINGS async_insert = 1;

-- date = '2024-01-03'
-- date = '2024-01-04'
-- a lote of data ...


-- Run optimiztion process
OPTIMIZE TABLE temp.table FINAL;


-- Final aggregated report
SELECT * FROM temp.table;

I need the last SELECT to return the correct sum, no matter how long it takes. Maybe there is some trick to deal with this kind of case? It's a bit frustrating when getting more data than it should be.

Don't use OPTIMIZE TABLE for any kind of business logic. (In fact, rarely should you ever run that command.)
Add FINAL after your table name and, at query time, the summing will occur:
SELECT * FROM temp.table FINAL;

Alternately, you can have FINAL be the default behavior of all queries:
SET final = 1;
SELECT * FROM temp.table;

Check the docs: https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/settings/settings#final

ORDER BY ( date, session );
means total field will aggregate for each combination of values for date and session fields
What exactly means the correct sum from you side?
Which sum do you expect?

I join the answer about FINAL clause and wanna add something:
If you don't want to always use final, you can try following settings
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp.table
(
    date     Date, 
    session  String, 
    total    Int32
)
ENGINE = SummingMergeTree
ORDER BY ( date, session )
SETTINGS min_age_to_force_merge_seconds=86400,min_age_to_force_merge_on_partition_only=1;

It will force clickhouse to do merges faster, but clickhouse does it on the background and full merge of rows is not guaranteed.
